# WPF pullable view from top to show alerts/notifictions like iOS devices

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can anyone suggest how to achieve a pullable view from top to show alerts/notifications like iOS devices in WPF?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the ability to click, hold, and drag it down? Or just click it and have a panel slide out or something? I'm not sure of the particular iOS effect you're referring to. Is this wpf, or a phone project, or winrt?

Comment: Its WPF application..click, hold and drag it down is an ideal solution but click and panel slide down is also fine. However I want to do it in a custom control so I can use it on multiple Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the popup control, which is more suitable for my situation. You can find documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it took so long to respond, been busy with my own projects. Anyway, the simplest route would just be click, which is real easy. Here's a concept example;

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="SlidePanelDown">
                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="SlidePanelUp">
                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0,-225,0,0"/>
                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked" SourceName="button">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlidePanelDown}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked" SourceName="button">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SlidePanelUp_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource SlidePanelUp}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>

            <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="100" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-225,0,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                       <Rectangle Fill="Green"/>
                       <ToggleButton x:Name="button" Grid.Row="1" Content="Click Me" Cursor="Hand"/>

                  </Grid>   
     </Grid>
```

To have it actually drag-able, it would require a bit more effort but is possible if you really want that effect, but this should be a good start. Hope this helps!

Comment: this solution also worked little bit, but I went ahead with Popup control

Comment: Ah, that's not the effect originally communicated but if it works it works! Cheers